# ¿Cómo resetear sombra campo de texto con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3, box-shadow

La idea es que cuando el campo este vacío se sombré de color rojo y cuando tenga datos se reseté a su estado original.

Lo que no puedo hacer es volverlo a su estado original.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#btnEnviar").click(function(event) {
  if($("#txt1").val() == ""){
    $("#txt1").css({
             "border-color": 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
             "box-shadow": '0 1px 0px rgba(229, 0, 0, 0.075)inset, 0 0 8px rgba(255,60,0,0.6)',
          "outline": "0 none"
           });
              }else{
               $("#txt1").css({
               "box-shadow": 'none',
            "outline": "0 none"
          });
              }
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
 <form action="">
  <input id="txt1" type="text">
  <button type="button" id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
 </form>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te faltaba setear el `border-color`.  Quedaria asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#btnEnviar").click(function(event) {
  if($("#txt1").val() == ""){
    $("#txt1").css({
             "border-color": 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
             "box-shadow": '0 1px 0px rgba(229, 0, 0, 0.075)inset, 0 0 8px rgba(255,60,0,0.6)',
          "outline": "0 none"
           });
              }else{
               $("#txt1").css({
               "border-color": 'initial',
               "box-shadow": 'none',
            "outline": "0 none"
          });
              }
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
 <form action="">
  <input id="txt1" type="text">
  <button type="button" id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
 </form>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo mismo iba a responder, buena respuesta.! :)

Comment: No me queda como el estado original, queda sombreado adentro, lo que quisiera es que volviera a verse como al inicio

Comment: Tienes razon.  Puedes setearlo con `initial`.  Ya edite mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta que encontre [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036857/how-can-i-remove-a-style-added-with-css-function) y solo es dejar vacías las propiedades del `.css`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#btnEnviar").click(function(event) {
  if($("#txt1").val() == ""){
    $("#txt1").css({
             "border-color": 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
             "box-shadow": '0 0 100px rgba(229, 0, 0, 0.075)inset, 0 0 8px rgba(255,60,0,0.6)',
          "outline": "0 none"
           });
              }else{
               $("#txt1").css({
               
               "border-color": "",
               "box-shadow": "",
            "outline": "0 none"
          });
              }
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
 <form action="">
  <input id="txt1" type="text">
  <button type="button" id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
 </form>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```